# Jenkins - How to stall a job until a notification is received?

Tags: http, curl, jenkins, automation

Is there anyway that a Jenkins job can be paused until a notification is received. Ideally with a payload as well?

I have a "test" job which does a whole bunch of remote tests and I'd like it to wait until the test are done where I send a HTTP notification via curl with a payload including a test success code.

Is this possible with any default Jenkins plugins?

Comment: usually I just make the first Jenkins job start the second one through the default Jenkins api

Answer (score 0):

If Jenkins 2.x is an option for you, I'd consider taking a look at writing a pipeline job.

See https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

Perhaps you could create a pipeline with multiple stages, where:

- The first batch of work (your test job) is launched by the first pipeline stage.
- That stage is configured (via Groovy code) to wait until your tests are complete before continuing. This is of course easy if the command to run your tests blocks, but if your tests launch and then detach without providing an easy way to determine when they exit, you can probably add extra Groovy code to your stage to make it poll the machine where the tests are running, to discover whether the work is complete.
- Subsequent stages can be run once the first stage exits.

As for passing a payload from one stage to another, that's possible too - for exit codes and strings, you can use Groovy variables, and for files, I believe you can have a stage archive a file as an artifact; subsequent stages can then access the artifact.

Or, as Hani mentioned in a comment, you could create two Jenkins jobs, and have your tests (launched by the first job) use the Jenkins API to launch the second job when they complete successfully.

As you suggested, curl can be used to trigger jobs via the API, or you can use a Jenkins API wrapper package for to your preferred language (I've had success using the Python jenkinsapi package for this sort of work: http://pythonhosted.org/jenkinsapi/)

If you need to pass parameters from your API client code to the second Jenkins job, that's possible by adding parameters to the second job using the the Parameterized Build features built into Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build